# Android XPath read failed: EBADF

Tags: android, xml, xpath

I am using XPath to read the contents of an Xml file stored locally in internal storage.

I have two methods. Each gets data from the xml file. The first method runs fine and works. The second method is almost the same as the first except it looks for different data. However, this method errors with read failed: EBADF.

The line that generates the error is in the ProcessEscalationLevels method.

```
NodeList nodes = (NodeList) xPath.evaluate(expression, source,
            XPathConstants.NODESET);
```

The two methods that get data plus the calling methods are below. Does anyone know what could be causing this error? I figure that it thinks the file stream is closed but am unable to work out why.

```
public void processSiteFile(File sitexml) throws IOException,
        XPathExpressionException {
    this.sitexml = sitexml;

    FileInputStream stream = new FileInputStream(this.sitexml);
    try {
        InputSource source = new InputSource(stream);
        XPath xPath = XPathFactory.newInstance().newXPath();

        // emergency category names
        processCategoryNames(xPath, source);

        // Process escalation levels
        processEscalationLevels(xPath, source);

    } finally {
        stream.close();
    }
}

private void processEscalationLevels(XPath xPath, InputSource source)
        throws XPathExpressionException, FileNotFoundException {

    String expression = "/site_settings/group_category_permission_list"
            + "/group_category_permission";
    NodeList nodes = (NodeList) xPath.evaluate(expression, source,
            XPathConstants.NODESET);

    if (nodes != null && nodes.getLength() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
            Element entry = (Element) nodes.item(i);

            // extract group id
            String tmpGroupId = xPath.evaluate("group_id", entry);
            int groupId = 0;
            if (tmpGroupId != null) {
                try {
                    groupId = Integer.valueOf(tmpGroupId);
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    groupId = 0;
                }
            }

            // extract category name
            String categoryName = xPath.evaluate("category_name", entry);
            if (categoryName == null)
                categoryName = ClientData.DEFAULT_CATEGORY;

            ClientData.GroupPermission permission = 
                    new ClientData.GroupPermission(groupId, categoryName);

            // extract escalation levels and add to permission
            NodeList permissionNodes = (NodeList) xPath.evaluate(
                    "escalation_level_list/escalation_level", entry,
                    XPathConstants.NODESET);

            for (int e = 0; e < permissionNodes.getLength(); e++) {
                Element permEntry = (Element) permissionNodes.item(e);

                // get seconds before escalating
                String tmpSecsBeforeEscalating = xPath.evaluate(
                        "secs_before_escalating", permEntry);
                int secsBeforeEscalating = 0;
                if (tmpSecsBeforeEscalating == null) {
                    secsBeforeEscalating = ClientData.DEFAULT_ESCALATION_TIME;
                } else {
                    secsBeforeEscalating = Integer
                            .valueOf(tmpSecsBeforeEscalating);
                }

                // get list of target group ids
                NodeList targetGroupNodes = (NodeList) xPath.evaluate(
                        "target_group_id_list/target_group_ids", permEntry,
                        XPathConstants.NODESET);
                Set<Integer> targetGroups = new HashSet<Integer>();
                for (int o = 0; o < targetGroupNodes.getLength(); o++) {
                    Node groupEntry = (Node) targetGroupNodes.item(o);
                    targetGroups.add(Integer.valueOf(groupEntry
                            .getTextContent()));
                }

                permission.escalationLevels
                        .add(permission.new EscalationLevel(targetGroups,
                                secsBeforeEscalating));
            }

            // Add permission to permission list
            ClientData.groupPermissions.add(permission);
        }
    }
}

private void processCategoryNames(XPath xPath, InputSource source)
        throws XPathExpressionException {
    String expression = "/site_settings/emergency_category_list"
            + "/emergency_category";
    NodeList nodes = (NodeList) xPath.evaluate(expression, source,
            XPathConstants.NODESET);

    if (nodes != null && nodes.getLength() > 0) {
        List<String> categories = new ArrayList<String>();

        for (int i = 0; i < nodes.getLength(); i++) {
            Node entry = nodes.item(i);

            if (entry.getNodeName() == "name") {
                categories.add(entry.getTextContent());

            } else if (entry.getNodeName() == "secs_before_repeating") {
                ClientData.secsBeforeRepeatingEmergency = Integer
                        .valueOf(entry.getTextContent());
            }
        }

        // Write category list to ClientData
        ClientData.emergencyCategory = (String[]) categories.toArray();

    } else {

        // Write a default category and repeat time
        ClientData.emergencyCategory = new String[] {
            ClientData.DEFAULT_CATEGORY
        };
        ClientData.secsBeforeRepeatingEmergency =
                ClientData.DEFAULT_EMERGENCY_REPEAT_TIME;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm unfamiliar with InputSources, but I see it wraps an InputStream. Perhaps the end of the stream has been reached at that point? You may want to try reading the source through an XPath linearly; that is to say, evaluating the XML as if the file pointer can only move continuously forward. If the problem persists, you'll have to supply your XML for me to give it a swing.

Comment: Hi Paul, Yes I have finally worked it out. As you say the end of the file was reached in the stream. To get around this I grab the Xml root node and use that instead of the source in all subsequent calls to XPath.evaluate. This way I don't need toe stream open after the first call to evaluate where I grab the root node! Dead chuffed I worked it out :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have finally worked it out. As you say the end of the file was reached in the stream. To get around this I grab the Xml root node and use that instead of the source in all subsequent calls to XPath.evaluate. This way I don't need toe stream open after the first call to evaluate where I grab the root node! Dead chuffed I worked it out :)